# Access raw GPS signal

Tags: gps

I have an android phone with GPS. Is there anyway to access the raw GPS signal. I want to export these signals into another platform, say Arduino. The interface between these two would be bluetooth, WiFi, wire, or any other method which would be available. The reason for this is that the GPS signal of the phone is accurate enough for me, rather than spending on GPS units with similar accuracy.
Any idea how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: When you say "raw" GPS signal, do you really just mean you want the lat/long coordinates ?

Comment: @CzarMatt Yes, I mean lat/long coordinates. Besides this, is there any other info I can get?

Comment: The NMEA data stream that comes out of the GPS module itself also includes the DOP and information on how many satellites are visible. Also, if you'd rather have a stream of locations instead of an NMEA stream, you can use Android's fused locations, which gives good results even when GPS is unavailable. Really, the question is, do you need the phone to look like a discrete GPS module, or can you accept any data format?